# Sql Server Database Books

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering how I would go about learning the functionality of all the different store procs and functions that come out of the box with sql server. Would I be right in saying that a book on sql server internals teach me all this?

Im pretty new to sql server and I have just finished volumes 1-3 out of 1-5 of Joes To Pros T-SQL querying 2012(Personally the writer is very good at putting together a book that enables you to learn and retain knowledge fast, but that's just my opinion).

Anyway, any help on this would be much appreciated. I love getting stuck into a good book as I think having structured learning with examples works best for me.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recommend any books in particular but I have several locations of free books on this page: http://sqlstudies.com/study-and-reference-tools/

For example this [page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11608.e-book-gallery-for-microsoft-technologies.aspx) has something like 30 free SQL books.

In general though you pick up the various DMOs and system views/functions as you study associated technologies.  For example you will learn about the replication DMOs etc as you study replication.

The [Periodic Table of DMOs](http://thesqlagentman.com/periodic-table/) by Tim Ford is a great place to start on the DMOs however.  It has all of the DMOs broken down by category and functional area.